# source/spec files for jdk 1.7

Tags: java, java-7, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have the rpm from Oracle's site, but I want to make some configuration changes and repackage the rpm. I don't see a source or spec file listed on their site and I don't want to have to build this whole thing out on my own...anyone have any suggestions or links to where I might be able to find this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when packaging the latest version of Redmine for CentOS.
I had to try several source rpms because of the initd/systemd differences between rpm distros, but I managed through rpmfind.

There seem to be several srpms for jdk 1.7 there:

http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-1.7.0-openjdk

a couple of Fedora Core ones and several from sourceforge.net (Fuduntu, Mageia, etc)